# Applying Template<class T> to multiple type aliases in one line

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a few type aliases like so:

```
template<class T> using v=vector<T>;
template<class T> using s=set<T>;
template<class T> using u_s=unordered_set<T>;
```

(Yes, I know this would make my code unreadable, and yes I know I'm using namespace std is bad.)

Is there shorter syntax, that works? I'm envisioning something like this but I know this won't work:

```
template<class T>{
using v=vector<T>;
using s=set<T>;
using u_s=unordered_set<T>;
}
```

I just don't see why I should have to write out template each and every time for the compiler to get what I mean. T is clearly some arbitrary type, can't I reuse it?

Comment: If you really want to save on typing you can use a macro.  On the other hand I would really suggest you not use such sort type names.  It's okay to use some extra keystrokes to make reading the code later eaiser.  I'd rather type `unordered_set<T>` all over the place then `u_s<T>`.

Comment: T is not clearly an arbitrary type. There's nothing stopping you declaring `class T; using v = vector<T>;`

Comment: @Fibbles your comment helped me understand why I can't do what I was proposing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not possible. The closest thing is to use macros (not that I recommend that):

```
#define TP template<class T>
TP using v = vector<T>;
TP using s = set<T>;
TP using u_s = unordered_set<T>;
#undef TP
```

You can't reuse `T` because the three alias have nothing to do with each other, so the `T` is (in general) different each time.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, I know this would make my code unreadable

I don't agree with that assessment. It is more readable than a macro based solution.

> and yes I know I'm using namespace std is bad.

I agree with you there.

Add the `std::` to the type names and you are good to go.

```
template<class T> using v = std::vector<T>;
template<class T> using s = std::set<T>;
template<class T> using u_s = std::unordered_set<T>;
```

There are much bigger fish to fry in a real world application. This is nowhere near your biggest problem. Don't worry too much about it. Move on to the next problem.

Comment: this does not answer the question

Comment: @NellieDanielyan That's true, but in his defense his/her answer taught me a new way to avoid using namespace std; when I'm lazy so I upvoted because I learned something.